# Does not update the component when clicking a button in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "TableConsolidado" component in which I have a button called "Test" that when clicked calls the "copiarDatos" function, in this function I do a "setDatosPorCopiar" to update the "DatosPorCopiar" state, in turn I handle a useEffect that when the state of this "DatosPorCopiar" changes, it will perform an action that is "mapDatosPorCopiar" in which I save data in firestore, the problem is that when I click on the "Test" button the component does not update

[image: 1]

```
const TableConsolidado = ({ confirmDelete, data, names, anio, mes }) => {
  const [datosPorCopiar, setDatosPorCopiar] = useState([]);
  const [helper, setHelper] = useState(false);

  const copiarDatos = () => {

    const meses = [
      "diciembre",
      "enero",
      "febrero",
    ];
    let mesAnterior;
    let anioNuevo = anio;

    if (mes === "diciembre") {
      // si el caso es diciembre, entonces el anterior es noviembre.
      mesAnterior = "noviembre";
    } else {
      // en cualquier otro caso, el mes anterior es el que se encuentra una posición antes en el arreglo de meses.
      const indiceMesActual = meses.indexOf(mes);
      mesAnterior = meses[indiceMesActual - 1];
    }

    if (mesAnterior === "diciembre") {
      anioNuevo = anio - 1;
    }

    data
      .filter((dat) => dat.mes === mesAnterior && dat.anio === anioNuevo)
      .map((da) =>
        setDatosPorCopiar((prevState) => [
          ...prevState,
          {
            anio: da.anio,
            dni: da.dni,
            id: da.id,
            lastName: da.lastName,
            mes: da.mes,
            montoPagado: da.montoPagado,
            name: da.name,
            notas: da.notas,
            phone: da.phone,
            price: da.price,
            roomName: da.roomName,
          },
        ])
      );
    console.log("se ejecuto copiar datos (pasar datos al state)");
  
       
  
  };

  const mapDatosPorCopiar = async () => {
    datosPorCopiar.map(async (datos) => {
      await addDoc(consolidadosCollection, {
        dni: datos.dni,
        anio: datos.anio,
        mes: mes,
        lastName: datos.lastName,
        name: datos.name,
        phone: datos.phone,
        price: datos.price,
        roomName: datos.roomName,
      });
      console.log("se guardaron los datos en la bd");
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (datosPorCopiar.length > 0) {
      console.log("ingreso al use effect y ejecuto");
      mapDatosPorCopiar();
    } else {
      console.log("ingreso pero no ejecuto");
    }
  }, [datosPorCopiar]);

  return (
    <>
      <hr />
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <div className="d-grid gap-2">
              <Link
                to="/createconsolidado"
                state={{ names: names, anio: anio, mes: mes }}
                className="btn btn-secondary mt-2 mb-2"
              >
                CREATE
              </Link>
            </div>

            <table className="table table-dark table-hover">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>CUARTO</th>
                  <th>DNI</th>
                  <th>NOMBRES</th>
                  <th>APELLIDOS</th>
                  <th>TELEFONO</th>
                  <th>PRECIO</th>
                  <th>MONTO PAGADO</th>
                  <th>NOTAS</th>
                  <th>ACCION</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {data
                  .filter((dat) => dat.mes === mes && dat.anio === anio)
                  .map((dat) => (
                    <tr key={dat.id}>
                      <td>{dat.roomName}</td>
                      <td>{dat.dni}</td>
                      <td>{dat.name}</td>
                      <td>{dat.lastName}</td>
                      <td>{dat.phone}</td>
                      <td>{dat.price}</td>
                      <td>{dat.montoPagado}</td>
                      <td>{dat.notas}</td>
                      <td>
                        <Link
                          to={`/edit/${dat.id}`}
                          state={{ names: names }}
                          className="btn btn-light"
                        >
                          <i className="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i>
                        </Link>
                        <button
                          onClick={() => {
                            confirmDelete(dat.id);
                          }}
                          className="btn btn-danger"
                        >
                          <i className="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
                        </button>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>

            <button onClick={copiarDatos} value={mes}>
              Test
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default TableConsolidado;
```

If more information is needed, please leave me a comment so I can update the post

I want the component to be updated when I click on the "test" button

Comment: Hey, when you ask `the component does not update` what are you expecting to be updated? Just because your mapping call is from data parameter, if you didn't change the content of the parameter nothing will be change in the UI. And finally, in the `setDatosPorCopiar` function you don't need the prevState, this value belongs to `datosPorCopiar`.

Comment: What I want to achieve is that when clicking on Test it is the following:
1. save the data made by the map in the "copyData" function (this data is saved in firebase)  ✓ Done
2. when i have the data save ready, i want to display the saved data in my table

Comment: where is the data coming from? Because that is what you are showing here. And if the data prop doesn't update there will be no changes in the DOM.

Comment: That useEffect is wrong since datosPorCopiar is a non-primitive data type, therefore it will re-render tnat useEffect without any change in the dependency. Here you have a post where you can read a bit more about this: https://dev.to/colocodes/6-use-cases-of-the-useeffect-reactjs-hook-282o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that the problem is that you are rending the data from the prop data. And if the data prop doesn't update there will be no changes in the dom to update.

So my guess is that the parent (or where the data comes from needs to be updated up there somewhere).

You can test this by changing data for datosPorCopiar and you will see changes. But I guess this is not what you want in the end.

```
           // This is the data I'm talking about.
           {data
              .filter((dat) => dat.mes === mes && dat.anio === anio)
              .map((dat) => (
                <tr key={dat.id}>
                  <td>{dat.roomName}</td>
                  <td>{dat.dni}</td>
                  <td>{dat.name}</td>
                  <td>{dat.lastName}</td>
                  <td>{dat.phone}</td>
                  <td>{dat.price}</td>
                  <td>{dat.montoPagado}</td>
                  <td>{dat.notas}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Link
                      to={`/edit/${dat.id}`}
                      state={{ names: names }}
                      className="btn btn-light"
                    >
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-pencil"></i>
                    </Link>
                    <button
                      onClick={() => {
                        confirmDelete(dat.id);
                      }}
                      className="btn btn-danger"
                    >
                      <i className="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
                    </button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
```